# Solr indexing related tables

Tags: solr

I have a solr instance with the DataImportHandler pointed at my database which has a few tables that map to a json like...

```
[ 
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Soap",
    "price": "2.00",
    "description": "It cleans things"
    "category_list: [
      {
        "id":1,
        "location": "store",
        "name": "cleaner"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "location": "online",
        "name": "home"
      }
   ]
}
```

Basically there are products which are in categories.

I pointed the indexer at this, but when I do queries for products I end up with results where the "categories" are split into separate lists

```
{
  name: ["cleaner", "home"]
  location: ["store", "online"]
  id: [1, 2]
}
```

It inverted the relationships and lost the context. If I wanted to ask it where the category location is "store" and the name is "home", it will find ANYTHING that has ANY inventory in a store and ANY category that is "home". It doesn't have the context to put it together in the same sub-object.

Is there a way to tell solr to index, store, and retrieve these correctly? I can feed it tables or json or whatever, but I want it back in the original shape, and I want to query it in the original shape.

So the data-config.xml is like this

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://pghostname:5432/db" user="user" password="pass" />
  <document >
    <entity name="products"
            pk="id"
            query="SELECT * from products">

      <field column="id" name="id"/>
      <field column="name" name="name"/>
      <field column="price" name="price"/>
      <field column="description" name="description"/>

      <entity name="product_categories"
            pk="category_id"
            query="SELECT * from product_categories where product_id = ${product.id}">

    <field column="category_id" name="category_id"/>
        <field column="location" name="location"/>
        <field column="name" name="name"/>

      </entity>

    </entity>

  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

And here's some sample data for a postgres database

```
create table products (
  id integer generated by default as identity,
  name varchar,
  price varchar,
  description varchar,
  primary key(id)
);

create table product_categories (
  category_id integer generated by default as identity,
  name varchar,
  location varchar,
  product_id integer,
  foreign key (product_id) references products(id),
  primary key(category_id)
);

insert into products
(name, price, description)
values
('Soap', '2.13', 'this is soap'),
('Pencils', '0.89', 'pencils write things'),
('Scissors', '5.00', 'scissors sciss');

insert into product_categories
(name, location, product_id)
values
('home', 'in-store', 1),
('office', 'online', 2),
('office', 'in-store', 3),
('home', 'in-store', 2);
```

You can see there's a single relationship. But after importing this and doing a query, we see results like...

```
"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "price":"2.13",
        "name":"Soap",
        "description":"this is soap",
        "id":"1",
        "category_id":"1",
        "location":"in-store",
        "_version_":1658459282145804288},
...
```

Which clearly flattened the two tables into one object

Comment: you should provide your DataImportHandler configuration.

Comment: Added some sample data and configurations